# Serilog does not send log to Elasticsearch asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, kibana

**I'm using Serilog and Elasticearch For my asp.net core app but when I open Kibana => Managment => DataViews, I can not find my application, and here is the configuration:**

**Program.cs**

```
builder.AddSerilog(builder.Configuration, "Appraisal360-Backend");
```

```
public static class SerilogExtensions
    {

        public static WebApplicationBuilder AddSerilog(this WebApplicationBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration, string applicationName)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", $"{applicationName} - {Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT")}")
                .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles"))
                .WriteTo.Async(writeTo => writeTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(configuration["ElasticsearchSettings:uri"]))
                {
                    TypeName = null,
                    AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                    IndexFormat = configuration["ElasticsearchSettings:defaultIndex"],
                    BatchAction = ElasticOpType.Create,
                    CustomFormatter = new EcsTextFormatter(),
                    //ModifyConnectionSettings = x => x.BasicAuthentication(configuration["ElasticsearchSettings:username"], configuration["ElasticsearchSettings:password"])
                }))
                .WriteTo.Async(writeTo => writeTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}"))
                .CreateLogger();

            builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
            builder.Host.UseSerilog(Log.Logger, true);

            return builder;
        }

        public static WebApplication UseSerilog(this WebApplication app)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
            app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(opts =>
            {
                opts.EnrichDiagnosticContext = LogEnricherExtensions.EnrichFromRequest;
            });

            return app;
        }
    }
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Hangfire": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "../logs/360-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {CorrelationId} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "ElasticsearchSettings": {
    "uri": "http://localhost:9200",
    "defaultIndex": "Appraisal360-BackEnd"
  },

  "ElasticApm": {
    "SecretToken": "",
    "ServerUrls": "http://192.168.62.66:8200", //Set custom APM Server URL (default: http://localhost:8200)
    "ServiceName": "Appraisal360-BackEnd", //allowed characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, _, and space. Default is the entry assembly of the application
    "Environment": "production" // Set the service environment
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**as you see I added all the configuration that needed, but the problem is that Kibana in ViewData could not find my Application**

**Note: My Elasticsearch and Kibana work without problem.**

Comment: first check if the index has been created, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ
No it is not created, I should change the question title first, tbh I know the problem with the code, but I don't know what is wrong with it.